# Modifying alltt

Tags: macros, verbatim, catcodes

I want to create an environment which wraps `alltt` in such a way that the character `'` is replaced by `\textquotesingle` wherever it occurs inside the environment but is as normal elsewhere. I have tried to replicate the tricks played in `upquote.sty` but have been unable to master the art of catcode hacking sufficiently to get it working. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{alltt,textcomp} % textcomp for \textquotesingle

\newenvironment{ualltt}
 {%
  \alltt % start alltt
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`' % make ~ a ' in \lowercase
  \lowercase{\endgroup\let~\textquotesingle}% make active ' call \textquotesingle
  \catcode`\'=\active % make ' active
 }
 {\endalltt}

\begin{document}
Some text
\begin{ualltt}
a'b'c
\end{ualltt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg, that certainly seems to do the trick. Could you please explain the use of ~ here?

Comment: @GrahamGough It's a nice trick: it exploits the fact that `~` is active, so when `\lowercase` is executed, `~` becomes an active `'`; the `\endgroup` is executed *after* `\lowercase` has performed its action.

Comment: I was reading the source code of `alltt` package, and noticed that it also uses the `\lowercase` trick (which forces it to treat specially the `'` char inside math). Why it is neccessary the `\lowercase` trick?

Comment: @JLDiaz Again, in order to make `'` in math mode expand to `\org@prime`; probably a different strategy could be used. Happily, my hack doesn't harm the standard working of `'` in math mode inside `alltt`.